# Swift: Right/Left click on NSStatusBar

Tags: swift, nsmenu, nsstatusbar

I'm building a `NSStatusBar` app and want to call different functions depending on if the user clicked left- or right on the icon.

Here is what I have so far:

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
    icon?.setTemplate(true)

    statusItem.image = icon
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
}
```

With this it shows up the `statusMenu` by every click. How can I distinguish the mouseEvents?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999700/detect-left-and-right-click-events-on-nsstatusitem-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect left and right click events on NSStatusItem (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999700/detect-left-and-right-click-events-on-nsstatusitem-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet

```
func menuSelected (sender:AnyObject) {
  var clickMask: Int = 0
  if let clickEvent = NSApp.currentEvent! {  // see what caused calling of the menu action
    // modifierFlags contains a number with bits set for various modifier keys
    // ControlKeyMask is the enum for the Ctrl key
    // use logical and with the raw values to find if the bit is set in modifierFlags
    clickMask = Int(clickEvent.modifierFlags.rawValue) & Int(NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue)
  }
  if clickMask != 0 { ... } // click with Ctrl pressed
}
```

from my code checks for a ctrl-click. It's place in the method that is called from a menu item like this:

```
let item = NSMenuItem(title: title, action: Selector("menuSelected:"), keyEquivalent: "")
```

Comment: See  NSEvent.pressedMouseButtons

Comment: Could you please add some comments to your code? Unfortunately I don't understand what's happening there. I'm not sure where to place it as well, since i haven't an IBAction.

Comment: I had a look into NSEvent too but had no luck getting left/right out of that. Will try a bit more. I used Ctrl-click to get different click variants for the status bar.

Comment: Dear Kilian, is there a Swift 3 solution for this?

Comment: My last try with Swift3 did hurt. I'm too old to work as early adopter and will be waiting for Swift4 to get mature before switching to Swift3. Go ahead and let that XCode make the transformation for you. Save your work before you do that :-/