# Call Action when NSStatusBarButton is right-clicked

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I am searching for a way to detect whenever the `NSStatusBarButton` is right-clicked (using Swift) and call an action.

I am currently setting it up this way:

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named: "myImage")
        button.alternateImage = NSImage(named: "myImage")
        button.action = Selector("myAction")
    }
}
```

I thought of using the `button.rightMouseDown(<#theEvent: NSEvent#>)` (Because there is no such "alternateAction") but unfortunately I did not manage to come up with something due to the fact that I just started programming Mac apps.

> #### Update:
>
> While searching for a way to do this I saw some threads telling to subclass a `NSView` but I don't se how this should work (This could be because I am really new to programming and don't even know how to "subclass"). Still I thought there was some easier way to use this since nearly every `statusBar` App that I know rects on right-clicks.

Comment: N.B This answer worked for me, though the bitmask syntax needs updating for Swift2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781167/swift-right-left-click-on-nsstatusbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass and override the `mouseDown` method, but since Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), there has been an easier way: [`NSGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSGestureRecognizer_Class/) and its subclasses:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named: "myImage")
        button.alternateImage = NSImage(named: "myImage")
        button.action = Selector("myAction")

        // Add right click functionality
        let gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.buttonMask = 0x2 // right mouse
        gesture.target = self
        gesture.action = "myRightClickAction:"
        button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}

func myRightClickAction(sender: NSGestureRecognizer) {
    if let button = sender.view as? NSButton {
        // Handle your right click event here
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all Thank you for your answer. UnfortunatelyI am getting a really bizarre issue. Using the `buttonMask = 0x2` it didn't detect right clicks at all, but changing the mask to `0x1` somehow it detected normal left clicks. This seems very weird to me since I haven't changed anything else at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you with the accepted answer's method: it didn't work for buttonMask 0x2, only buttonMask 0x1. Regular `NSButton`s (but not `NSStatusBarButtons`) can handle `NSClickGestureRecognizer`s, so perhaps that's what the answerer was thinking. Another solution I found suggested was to set the `NSStatusItem`'s `view` to an instance of your own custom subclass of `NSView`, but as of OS X v10.10, getting or setting `view` is deprecated, so I didn't want to do that.

I solved this by adding a custom subclass of `NSView` as a subview of the `NSStatusItem`'s button. My `NSView` implements `-rightMouseUp:` to receive the right mouse up event and then just passes that event to a block given to it by my class that wants to handle the right mouse click event.

Here's my custom subclass:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TTRightClickDetector : NSView

@property (copy) void (^onRightMouseClicked)(NSEvent *);

@end

#import "TTRightClickDetector.h"
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation TTRightClickDetector

- (void)rightMouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if(self.onRightMouseClicked)
    {
        self.onRightMouseClicked(theEvent);
    }
}

@end
```

And here's how I use it:

```
self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];
NSStatusBarButton *button = self.statusItem.button;
button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"image"];
button.action = @selector(leftMouseClicked:);

TTRightClickDetector *rightClickDetector = [[TTRightClickDetector alloc] initWithFrame:button.frame];
rightClickDetector.onRightMouseClicked = ^(NSEvent *event){
    [self rightMouseClicked];
};
[button addSubview:rightClickDetector];
```

Answer (score 0):

The swift version of commanda's answer (subclassing an NSView and implementing mouseDown).

NSView Subclass:

```swift
class RightMouseHandlerView: NSView {

    var onRightMouseDown: (()->())? = nil

    override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.rightMouseDown(with: event)

        if onRightMouseDown != nil {
            onRightMouseDown!()
        }
    }
}
```

Then adding it to the status bar button and setting the code block:

```swift
statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

if let button = statusItem.button {
    let rmhView = RightMouseHandlerView(frame: statusItem.button!.frame)
    rmhView.rightMouseDown = {
        // Do something when right mouse down on button
    }
    button.addSubview(rmView)
}
```