# Detect left and right click events on NSStatusItem (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem, nsevent, nsstatusbar

I’m building a status bar app and want to call different actions depending on if the user clicked left or right. Here’s what I have so far:

```
var statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: -1)
statusItem.action = #selector(AppDelegate.doSomeAction(sender:))

let leftClick = NSEventMask.leftMouseDown
let rightClick = NSEventMask.rightMouseDown

statusItem.button?.sendAction(on: leftClick)
statusItem.button?.sendAction(on: rightClick)

func doSomeAction(sender: NSStatusItem) {
    print("hello world")
}
```

My function is not called and I couldn’t find our why. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
button.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
```

Then seeing which mouse button was pressed in the `doSomeAction()` function?

So it will look something like...

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSSquareStatusItemLength)

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.action = #selector(self.doSomeAction(sender:))
        button.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
    }

}

func doSomeAction(sender: NSStatusItem) {

    let event = NSApp.currentEvent!

    if event.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
        // Right button click
    } else {
        // Left button click
    }

}
```

Thanks to @dbrownjave for noticing the change in Swift 4 from `NSEventType.rightMouseUp` to `NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp`.

https://github.com/craigfrancis/datetime/blob/master/xcode/DateTime/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: this does work indeed, but seems to only like `.rightMouseUp`, not `.rightMouseDown`

Comment: Did you also change the `button.sendAction` line?

Comment: doh! changed in the `sendAction`, not in the statement! works just fine, thanks x)

Comment: How would I do this with the NSEventMask.scrollWheel?

Comment: How can I open a contextual menu only when I right click the item? I read that `popUpStatusItemMenu` is deprecated, and I could not understand how to do it in Swift 4...

Comment: Make sure to also accept control-click: `if event.type == .rightMouseUp || (event.modifierFlags.contains(.control) && event.type == .leftMouseUp)`

Comment: I don't know how this is working for you guys without setting the target in the button, it only works for me when I do `statusItem.button!.target = self`

Comment: @bithavoc, Does the other answer below work for you, ref Swift 4, which uses `NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp`?

Comment: @CraigFrancis yes it worked, thank you very much. I realized since `self` is not in the responder chain, then I had to set the `button.target` manually.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated: SWIFT 4**

I've updated (Craig Francis) answer

```
func doSomeAction(sender: NSStatusItem) {

    let event = NSApp.currentEvent!

    if event.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp{
        // Right button click
    } else {
        // Left button click
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more as to why this code works and what it does to solve the problem?